# Showing any finite algebra is a sigma algebra

Tags: measure-theory, statistics

How do I establish that any finite algebra is automatically a $\sigma$-algebra (on a given space $\Omega$)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

every countable union of elements of the algebra can be written as a finite union of elements of the algebra, since there can only be a finite number of distinct terms in the union.